# Select seasonal data from long-term yearly series

Tags: r, lubridate

I have time-series data with years, months, and days. But I want to select seasonal data for each year. How can I select data ranging from 24 April-28 September for each year?

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag and, in particular, provide sampe data using `dput`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a possible approach using the `yday()` (i.e. day-of-year) function from `lubridate`

```
# sample data
mydates <- seq(as.Date("2022-01-01"), as.Date("2023-12-31"), by = "1 days")
mydata <- data.frame(id =  seq.int(length(mydates)),
                     date = mydates)
# load libraries required)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
# set constants for subsetting
# from = March 30th (format %m-%d)
datefrom = "03-30"
# until = April 2nd (format %m-%d)
dateto = "04-02"
mydata %>%
  # get the subset start and end day-of-year (accounting for leap years)
  mutate(from = lubridate::yday(as.Date(paste0(lubridate::year(date), "-", datefrom))),
         to = lubridate::yday(as.Date(paste0(lubridate::year(date), "-", dateto)))) %>%
  # filter the rows between the from-to numbers
  filter(dplyr::between(lubridate::yday(date), from, to)) %>%
  # deselect the temp columns
  select(-c("from", "to"))

#    id       date
# 1  89 2022-03-30
# 2  90 2022-03-31
# 3  91 2022-04-01
# 4  92 2022-04-02
# 5 454 2023-03-30
# 6 455 2023-03-31
# 7 456 2023-04-01
# 8 457 2023-04-02
```